# Build something that requires dh-python

Tags: raspbian

I have written a couple Python programs and packaged them for Ubuntu. There, I use the `dh-python` helper which replaces `python-support` and `python-central` in the build process. With Raspian, which is based off Wheezy, I tried to build my packages but did not find `dh-python` in the repository. Debian only has this in “Wheezy Backports”, but Raspbian does not have the backports.

How can I get a working package for the `armhf`, ARMv6+VFP2, architecture that the Pi has?

Since the Python packages are build for `all` and not a specific architecture, I could set up a VM with Wheezy and its backports, install `dh-python`, build the packages and install them on the Pi. Does that make sense?